# How to click on multiple checkboxes based on value through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I am trying to select multiple checkboxes. Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-sections">
      <ul>
         <li>Select permissions</li>
         <li><input type="checkbox" id="permissions1549733530963" name="permissions"><label for="permissions1549733530963">Select all</label></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="searchbox-container">
         <div class="check-list">
            <ul>
               <li><input type="checkbox" id="371549733530963" name="permissions" value="Add User"><label for="371549733530963">Add User</label></li>
               <li><input type="checkbox" id="31549733530965" name="permissions" value="View User"><label for="31549733530965">View User</label></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to select only two checkbox. I'm doing this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' && @name='permissions' && @value='"+value+'"")).click();
```

here id tag is generated randomly. How to select multiple checkboxes based on the value tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using string array I did this. Please try.

```
String[] users = {"Add/Update Network Security", "Create User"};
int size = users.length;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    String value=users[i];
    System.out.println(value);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @value='" +value +"']"))).click();               
}
```

Or

```
String[] users = {"Add/Update Network Security", "Create User"};
int size = users.length;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    String value=users[i];
    System.out.println(value);
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @value='" +value +"']"));
               JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
               js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);                           
}
```

Comment: didn't worked same error org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Comment: I have added some wait to visible of your element.can you try that.

Comment: If your application is slow you can increase the wait time.

Comment: I tired 50 instead of 30. it says org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@type='checkbox' and @value='Add Network'] (tried for 50 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Ok.Try this one I have trired with javascripts executor.

Comment: Great JavascriptExecutor  worked. Could please tell why JavascriptExecutor ?

Comment: Possibly the element was hidden in the page so better to use java scripts executor when locator like xpath , css unable to find the element.Could you please vote for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To click on any of the *check boxes* you can create a function as follows:

```
public void locateClickCheckbox(String item)
{
    String myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-sections']//div[@class='check-list']//li/input[@value='" + item + "']"))).getAttribute("id");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-sections']//div[@class='check-list']//li/label[@for='" + myElement + "']"))).click();
}
```

Now you can call the function from anywhere within your program as:

```
locateClickCheckbox("Add/Update Network Security")
locateClickCheckbox("Create User")
locateClickCheckbox("Create Project")
locateClickCheckbox("Update User Details")
locateClickCheckbox("View User")
locateClickCheckbox("Assign Permissions")
```